How can I manage corresponding types of routes and transports in database?
I need help to manage relationship in a database of urban transport for my practical work. I have 3 entities with the following attributes:
Route:
-route_id(PK)  
-passengers_day(avg passengers a day using this route)  
-first_trip(scheduled time for first trip)  
-last_trip(scheduled time for last trip)  
-interval_mins(time interval between transports on a route)

Transport:
-license_plate_no(PK)(varchar as 111AZ11)  
-manufacture_date  
-num_repairs(how many times transport has been repaired)

TypeOfTransport:
-type_id(PK)  
-name(e.g. bus/trolleybus/electro bus)  
-fare(cost for trip)  
-avg_speed  
-cars_at_park(total number of transports available at park)

Todo: add FKs to build relationships between entities.
I couldn't find a proper way to build relationships with these entities so that each route has one type and has many transports, and also each transport has one type and can only be assigned to one route (but can be switched to another), but both routes and transports should have same typeoftransport.
I did try to solve it this way: drawio diagram and left the mapping process between route and transport types to the check constraints.
But this didn't seem right to me because it creates a transitive relationship between the route and transport entities. I read about subtypes and supertypes, but I have no idea how to use them in my case.
